# How to fix error: Could not symlink lib/gcc/4.9?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, homebrew, gcc

I would like to install `gcc` with `homebrew` on a MacBook Pro (OS X 10.10.3) and ran into this:

```
mach:gcc mh$ brew install gcc
Warning: gcc-4.9.2_1 already installed, it's just not linked
mach:gcc mh$ brew link gcc
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1... 
Error: Could not symlink lib/gcc/4.9
/usr/local/lib/gcc is not writable.
```

What can I do? (adjusting the permissions of `/usr/local/lib/gcc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error:

> /usr/local/lib/gcc is not writable.

means that your `/usr/local/lib` folder is not writable for `brew`.

Therefore you should fix the wrong permissions first by:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include /usr/local/bin /usr/local/Cellar
```

Then if this still doesn't work, run:

```
brew doctor
```

to check your system for potential other problems which you may have.

Similar issue: [Brew doctor says: “Warning: /usr/local/include isn't writable.”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14527521/55075) at SO

Comment: Thanks for helping. I think it should be `-R` (uppercase). Before changing permissions, I checked (in the Terminal) and they were already set correctly, but executing `chown` indeed helped. Seems strange.

Comment: @MariusHofert I've fixed typo, thanks. Sometimes when you run `brew` with `sudo`, it breaks the permissions, so you've to re-run the `chown` again then.